# How to assign random normal values for each cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random, normalization

I have a dataset based on a 5-point Likert scale. I want to transform each cell into a normal distribution value with pregiven mean and std. My code for now is as follows.

```
import random
Mu={1:0.021,2:0.146,3:0.375,4:0.625,5:0.979}
std={1:0.021,2:0.104,3:0.125,4:0.125,5:0.021}

#defining the random dictionary 
rnd={1:random.normalvariate(Mu[1], std[1]),
    2:random.normalvariate(Mu[2], std[2]),
    3:random.normalvariate(Mu[3], std[3]),
    4:random.normalvariate(Mu[4], std[4]),
    5:random.normalvariate(Mu[5], std[5])}

raw_data_rnd=raw_data.copy()

for col in raw_data_rnd.columns:
    raw_data_rnd[col].mask(raw_data_rnd[col]==1,random.normalvariate(Mu[1],std[1]),inplace=True)
    raw_data_rnd[col].mask(raw_data_rnd[col]==2,random.normalvariate(Mu[2],std[2]),inplace=True)
    raw_data_rnd[col].mask(raw_data_rnd[col]==3,random.normalvariate(Mu[3],std[3]),inplace=True)
    raw_data_rnd[col].mask(raw_data_rnd[col]==4,random.normalvariate(Mu[4],std[4]),inplace=True)
    raw_data_rnd[col].mask(raw_data_rnd[col]==5,random.normalvariate(Mu[5],std[5]),inplace=True)
raw_data_rnd
```

The code is working. However, it gives the same value for every cell where the condition is true. What I need is for the code to somehow loop the random value assignment and put a different value in each cell. In other words, for instance every time the dataframe has the value of 1, I need the code to assign a new random value.

Can anyone help, please?

I have tried several methods. However, I am still hitting deadends.

Comment: Do you only values between 1 and 5 in your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the counts of each values (between 1 and 5) then [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace values by a random number with [`np.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) according the `mu` and `std` parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# For reproducible result
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

# Sample dataframe: 4 columns, 20 rows, values between 1 and 9
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(1, 10, (20, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# DON'T KEEP THIS STEP
df = df.astype(float)  # important to cast dataframe as float
arr = df.values  # get a "view" of the dataframe

# Get number of occurrence for each number between 1 and 5
dmap = dict(zip(*np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)))

# Replace values
for i in range(1, 6):
    rnd = rng.normal(Mu[i], std[i], dmap[i])
    arr[np.where(arr == i)] = rnd
```

Output:

```
# After processing
>>> df
           A         B         C         D
0   0.036608  7.000000  6.000000  0.583139
1   0.645344  8.000000  0.032406  7.000000
2   0.216607  0.007024  0.955201  9.000000
3   7.000000  7.000000  7.000000  8.000000
4   0.959692  0.153028  8.000000  0.989440
5   0.981991  0.698278  0.176068  9.000000
6   8.000000  6.000000  0.713903  8.000000
7   0.993500  0.724168  0.970028  0.340607
8   0.025875  0.982329  8.000000  0.023450
9   8.000000  8.000000  0.561868  6.000000
10  0.211654  7.000000  7.000000  0.581409
11  0.025592  9.000000  0.992137  9.000000
12  7.000000  8.000000  7.000000 -0.005544
13  0.567206  0.972504  0.988592  0.039300
14  0.965100  0.112754  7.000000  7.000000
15  9.000000  7.000000  0.732247  9.000000
16  0.601087  0.266771  9.000000  0.465539
17  0.025696  0.971376  8.000000  0.097081
18  0.970984  0.079557  7.000000  0.953887
19  0.496035  0.164641  6.000000  7.000000

>>> dmap
{1.0: 8, 2.0: 8, 3.0: 5, 4.0: 10, 5.0: 14, 6.0: 4, 7.0: 14, 8.0: 10, 9.0: 7}
```

Input data:

```
# Before processing
>>> df
    A  B  C  D
0   1  7  6  4
1   4  8  1  7
2   2  1  5  9
3   7  7  7  8
4   5  2  8  5
5   5  4  2  9
6   8  6  4  8
7   5  4  5  3
8   1  5  8  1
9   8  8  3  6
10  2  7  7  4
11  1  9  5  9
12  7  8  7  2
13  4  5  5  1
14  5  2  7  7
15  9  7  4  9
16  4  3  9  4
17  1  5  8  2
18  5  2  7  5
19  3  3  6  7
```